# can't use ssh with dockerized Gitlab

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab

I've installed the latest gitlab using docker on centos 7

```
docker run -d --hostname git.xxxx.com \
-p 8082:80 -p 22:22 \
--name gitlab \
--restart always \
-v /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab:Z \
-v /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab:Z \
-v /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab:Z \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

I also changed the host ssh port to 10022 and let gitlab use port 22.
Gitlab ran successful. Cloning worked using http but fails when using ssh.

```
git clone git@git.xxxx.com:yphc/dt-dd-miniprogram.git

Cloning into 'dt-dd-miniprogram'...
ssh: connect to host git.xxxx.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Output from checking Gitlab status:

```
root@git:/# gitlab-ctl status
run: gitaly: (pid 472) 241405s; run: log: (pid 467) 241405s
run: gitlab-monitor: (pid 474) 241405s; run: log: (pid 465) 241405s
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 471) 241405s; run: log: (pid 464) 241405s
run: logrotate: (pid 15611) 203s; run: log: (pid 456) 241405s
run: nginx: (pid 475) 241405s; run: log: (pid 469) 241405s
run: node-exporter: (pid 460) 241406s; run: log: (pid 459) 241406s
run: postgres-exporter: (pid 453) 241406s; run: log: (pid 452) 241406s
run: postgresql: (pid 470) 241406s; run: log: (pid 463) 241406s
run: prometheus: (pid 482) 241406s; run: log: (pid 476) 241406s
run: redis: (pid 396) 241408s; run: log: (pid 395) 241408s
run: redis-exporter: (pid 455) 241406s; run: log: (pid 454) 241406s
run: sidekiq: (pid 473) 241406s; run: log: (pid 468) 241406s
warning: sshd: unable to open supervise/ok: access denied
run: unicorn: (pid 466) 241406s; run: log: (pid 458) 241406s
```

***warning: sshd: unable to open supervise/ok: access denied***

I tried the ssh command in the gitlab container which worked. I also added port 22 to the firewall.

```
[root@localhost zones]# firewall-cmd --list-all 
    public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp2s0
  sources: 
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports: 2022/tcp 10022/tcp 22/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

And when I close firewall it says

```
    Cloning into 'dt-dd-miniprogram'...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I looked around on the internet for a long time but couldn't find anything. I'd be grateful for any help or ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: check https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20226

Answer (score 1):

In my case was a permission problem. It seems that the ssh keys are saved with 0777 permission, that prevents ssh from starting.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0777 for '/etc/gitlab/ssh_host_xxxxxxx_key' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
key_load_private: bad permissions
Could not load host key: /etc/gitlab/ssh_host_xxxxxxx_key
```

You can login inside your dockerize Gitlab with
`docker exec -it gitlab_web_1 /bin/bash`

check why is not started with
`cat /var/log/gitlab/sshd/current`

If you see similar logs a quick fix is
`chmod 0770 /etc/gitlab/ssh_host_*`

Then restart `ssh` service with
`/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

Now you should see something like this in the log file

```
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Server listening on :: port 22.
```

Another (related) problem can be that the volume that you use for the `config` folder is on a windows fs (ntfs?). In this case:

- if you use a linux host BUT the volumes are on a ntfs mount, try setting only for `config` folder a different path BUT on a linux fs (that supports file permission). On my ntfs mount for example I have all files with 0777 permissions and cannot be changed
- if you use windows try setting files to more restrictive permission

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up in the same situation with the official gitlab-ce docker image after migrating from kvm.

```
root@gitlab:/opt/gitlab# /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv start sshd
warning: sshd: unable to open supervise/ok: access denied
```

I've found that this sv generates the error:

```
root@gitlab:/opt/gitlab# /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv start sshd
warning: sshd: unable to open supervise/ok: access denied
```

Because /opt/gitlab/sv/sshd/supervise/ok pipe is not accessible for root:

```
root@gitlab:/opt/gitlab/sv/sshd/supervise# cat ok
cat: ok: Permission denied
```

And just as a test I've updated it with 777 permissions, but still no luck

```
root@gitlab:/opt/gitlab/# /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv start sshd
fail: sshd: runsv not running
```

The workaround I've used is in my Dockerfile that is based on gitlab-ce:latest:

```
RUN sed -i '/gitlab-ctl reconfigure/a service ssh start' /assets/wrapper
```

This would start up ssh and now I can connect with git user via ssh to push and pull :)

Don't forget you would need proper env set up for the ports you want to use https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/

```
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'http://gitlab.m31.com:3080'
      gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 3022
```

*So things are working now, but keep in mind that this is an odd/ugly workaround and I'm sure there is a better way to make this work.*

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing on another centos 7, everything is OK , so I guess the OS has some error, the gitlab docker is OK, but I can't find it up till now
thx

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to have two servers on one host use the same port `22` is to bind them to separate IP addresses. By default, both `gitlab` and `sshd` bind to `0.0.0.0` and therefore reserve that port on all addresses and interfaces.

Allocating additional public ip addresses to your machine is possible by your hosting provider, they should register in `ifconfig` on the host.

Your local ssh server should bind to your *primary ip address*. Look in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

Docker can port-forward to specific ip's using `-p <secondary_ip>:22:22`

You can setup sub-domains such as `git.example.com` for the secondary ip, and `server.example.com` for the primary ip.

Comment: Another alternative, of course, is to put a TCP load balancer in front of the system.